# Write MetaData to text box

Tags: c++, qt, metadata, mp3

I am currently trying to get the Metadata to display when building a MP3 play.

However, I am having problems displaying the information. It seems to be reading it with the current code.

```
 void Widget::on_SongName_objectNameChanged(const QString)
   {
      QString title = player->metaData("title").toString();
   }
```

I don't know where to go next

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display the metadata in the QTextEdit or QLabel? Then do:

```
myTextBox->setText( title );
```

Comment: QText Editor What library do I need to get the setText point from?

Comment: A text editor is the Qt edit text field you add in designer. Also you can use QLabel. Both are in the QtGui library.